# Can I safely finish Volare if I plan on doing Change in Management?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

The title pretty much says it all. On the one hand, the Boomers are freakin' nuts. On the other, I'm guessing that raising that bomber out of the lake and watching it rain fiery death over the Legion is going to be the ultimate "wow" moment.

So... Is it safe to finish Volare if I plan on completing Wild Card: Change in Management and either ruling New Vegas or making it independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volare is required or optional for all four main quest paths. At it's conclusion, you convince the Boomers to support *you*, not any particular faction. You can even inform Ambassador Crocker/House/Yes Man of this fact without locking you into a path -  just choose your words carefully when you do so.

Comment: Or, well, choose your speech options carefully. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've completed Volare and even told the NCR I did, before completing the entire main quest the Wild Card route. As far as I know, Volare is required for the main quest (at least for the main factions). Telling the NCR you will help them will of course stop you from going the Legion route.